# How can I show a DIV by it's attribute value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a Jquery plugin and I would like to trigger the modal (div) by calling it's value instead of calling it's ID name.
So if the attribute value is "554" meaning attrId="554" I will display the modal with the matching "554" attribute. Please keep in mind that the attribute value could be a variable.

[My JSFiddle Code Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1001/3eb26vhd/)

```
;(function($) {

     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): `[attribute="value"]`

If your popup div has an attribute like this:

```
<div id="element_to_pop_up" attrId="554">
    <a class="b-close">x</a>
    Content of popup
</div>
```

You can use the following:

```
var x = '554';
$('div[attrId="' + x + '"]').bPopup();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmmy3xto/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it needs a unique selector unless you are okay with triggering multiple modals. One way to do it is to use the jQuery each function, and check each div for the matching attribute.

```
$( "div" ).each(function() {
    var criteria = 'example_criteria';
    if ($( this ).attr( "attributename" ) == criteria)
    {
         $(this).bPopup();
    }
});
```